# Adaptor for a Mic Headset with a telephone-like connector (6P6C, RJ11, RJ12...)

Tags: audio, connector

I have got a bunch (15+) of old headsets with microphones that use a [6P6C connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#6P6C), (like those RJ11 for telephone lines but with 6 contacts). I would like to use them for a computer classroom connecting each to a PC. The microphone is not important for me. Just hearing sound is OK. I guess I could cut them out and solder one or two mini jacks, but I am looking for an easier solution.

I would say that I need an adaptor with a female 6P6C jack and two male mini jacks. The adaptors I can find online are usually [the opposite](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/2X3-5mm-Headset-RJ11-Phone-Adapter-Suit-Siemens-Revo/1345661535.html). ¿Does it exist?

Other working options would be appreciated:

¿Is it possible to use them through a regular modem? ¿And through an USB adaptor?

Comment: "Is it possible to use them through a regular modem" -- I'm not sure what relevance a modem has to your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, I am thinking of one of my old PCI modems because it has a female connector as needed. Just as a desperate example of a possible workaround...